# React - Empty Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working in a project where I'm trying to set the options of a dropdown with an array of objects that I'm getting from a request to an API. The problem is that when the program is compiled, it doesn't throw any option.

Here is my code:

```
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

type formProps = {
    funcionCierre: any
    carrera: any;
    nombre1: any;
}

const Estudiantes: React.FC<formProps> = (props: formProps) => {

    const [area, setArea] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const [areaSeleccionada, setAreaSeleccionada] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.carrera);
        axios.get('http://localhost:8003/skill?carrera_id=' + props.carrera + '&tipo_id=1')
            .then(result => {
                setArea(result.data);
            }

            ).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }, [area.length]);


    const actualizarAreaSelect = (e: any) => {
        setAreaSeleccionada(e.target.value)
        console.log(areaSeleccionada);
    }

    return (
               <Dropdown
                 placeholder='Area'
                 options={area.map(ar => ({
                 key: ar.skil_id,
                 value: ar.skill_id,
                 text: ar.nombre
                 }))}
                 onChange={actualizarAreaSelect}
                />

    );
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you are updating the state in `useEffect()` at the same time that `useEffect()` has dependency the state. It means you might be in an infinite loop.

Comment: Just use an empty dependency array so the options are fetched only once when the component mounts.

Comment: Even though `area.length` should not be put in the dependency list and `props.carrera` should, and `key: ar.skil_id,` might be a typo, fixing those may not solve the problem. What do you get from `result.data`? Could you please try to `console.log` it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `area` is set from the results of the API call, you shouldn't include `[area.length]` in the second argument of `useEffect`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.carrera);
        axios.get('http://localhost:8003/skill?carrera_id=' + props.carrera + '&tipo_id=1')
            .then(result => {
                setArea(result.data);
            }

            ).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    });
```