# React - how to stop useEffect from being called continuously without altering dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am working on a project and I am having problems with the `useEffect` hook and a dropdown. Earlier I asked a question where I was suggested to remove the second argument from `useEffect` ([React - Empty Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62338536/react-empty-dropdown)), but by doing that, `useEffect` loads constantly, i.e. it makes the same request to the server without stopping.

Here is my code:

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';

    type formProps = {
        funcionCierre: any
        carrera: any;
        nombre1: any;
    }

    const Estudiantes: React.FC<formProps> = (props: formProps) => {

        const [area, setArea] = useState<any[]>([]);
        const [conocimiento, setConocimiento] = useState<any[]>([]);
        const [areaSeleccionada, setAreaSeleccionada] = useState(0);

        useEffect(() => {//this is the request that it makes without stopping
            axios.get('http://localhost:8003/skill?carrera_id=' + props.carrera + '&tipo_id=1')    
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(result);                    
                    setArea(result.data);
                }

                ).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });

        });

        const actualizarAreaSelect = (e: any) => {
            setAreaSeleccionada(e.target.value)
        }

        return (
                                    <Dropdown
                                        placeholder='Area'
                                        options={area.map(ar => ({
                                            key: ar.skil_id,
                                            value: ar.skill_id,
                                            text: ar.nombre
                                        }))}
                                        onChange={actualizarAreaSelect}
                                    />

        );
    }
```

I need to know how to stop it (because that affects the server) without altering the dropdown.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to add [] as your 2nd arg in your useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, this API request only needs to run once. Therefore, you should be using an empty array as the dependency array, which will ensure that it will only be run when the component is first rendered.

```
useEffect(() => {//this is the request that it makes without stopping
        axios.get('http://localhost:8003/skill?carrera_id=' + props.carrera + '&tipo_id=1')    
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);                    
                setArea(result.data);
            }

            ).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }, []);
```